# Comparing text field and Selection List value and alert

Tags: javascript

I have a text field in which value gets populated when screen loads and also have a selection list.

My question is when user selects a value in Selection List and compares with the text field and trigger an alert message if its not equal.

Please help!

```
    JS:
function doType() 
{
    if (document.getElementById("Text1").value != document.getElementById("Select1").value) 
    alert(document.getElementById("Select1").value)
}

HTML:
<tr>
        <td align="right"><b>Select 1:</b></td>
        <td align=left>
           <select name="Select1" onChange="doType();"></select>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><b> Text 1:</b></td>
        <td align="left">
            <input name="Text1" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10">
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: JS:
 function doType() 
 {
  if (document.getElementById("Text1").value != document.getElementById("Select1").value) 
  alert(document.getElementById("Select1").value)
 }

    HTML:
 <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Select 1:</b></td>
            <td align=left>
               <select name="Select1" onChange="doType();"></select>
            </td>
            <td align="right"><b> Text 1:</b></td>
            <td align="left">
                <input name="Text1" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10">
            </td>
        </tr>

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
function doType()
    {
      if(document.getElementById("Select1").value === document.getElementById("Text1").value){
        alert("Equal");
       }

      else{
       alert(" Not Equal");
      }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="Select1"onChange="doType();">
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Orange</option>
<option>Pineapple</option>
<option>Banana</option>
</select>

<input id="Text1" type="text" value="Apple"/>
```

Comment: I tried but not working :( i tried giving alert of text field value and selection list value separately. text field value is not coming

Comment: that is because you didnt gave the `id` to both Selectbox and textfield. You must assign `id` to every element in order to access their value in Javascript